# Interactive mathematical constructions application

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I'm a big fan of maths, and I was wondering if there is some sort of interactive mathematical application which would allow one to?:

- Construct lines and shapes with points
- Calculate interior and exterior angles on shapes as well as intersecting lines etc
- Calculate the lengths and slopes of lines
- Calculate perimeters, and areas of shapes
- Can draw specific types of lines accurately, such as, perpendicular, parallel, angle bisector, tangents, and perpendicular bisectors etc
- Ability to translate shapes via vectors
- Ability to reflect shapes in points, lines, and circles
- Ability to enlarge shapes from points via vectors
- Ability to export completed work into PNG, animated GIF and HTML webpage format

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GeoGebra` is just the app for you! **Install** it with:

```
sudo apt-get install geogebra
```

**Description:**

```
Dynamic mathematics software for education
GeoGebra is a dynamic geometry program. You can do constructions with points,
vectors, segments, lines, conic sections as well as functions and change
them dynamically afterwards. On the other hand, equations and coordinates
can be entered directly.
Support for many geometric constructions is provided, as well as support
for many calculus-based tools (derivatives, osculating circle, ...).
GeoGebra files can be exported in many different formats, or as interactive
applets for web pages.
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice application! Worth mentioning.

Comment: My mother used to make me "play" with the computer by teaching me GeoGebra. It was quite some fun creating the geometric pictures. Though I must say it's been years since I last used it.

Comment: Well, it's a great application, I'm so happy to have found it! :)